# Grails plugin cxf-client-1.5.4 failover

Tags: grails-2.2, cxf-client, retrypolicy

Downloaded cxf-client-1.5.4 from Maven Repository, does not contain any configuration for fail-over features about retry strategy. However, during heavy load and slowness in production, I observed and suspected from the log that retry is happening.

Is there any retry strategy configured in CXF plug-in for Grails ? If yes, how to stop retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stress test and applying different measures in application confirmed that there is no retry strategy in Grails cxf-client-1.5.4.